# JAR - extracting specific files

Tags: java, jar, extract, archive

I have .class and .java files in JAR archive. Is there any way to extract only .java files from it?
I've tried this command but it doesn't work:

```
jar xf jar-file.jar *.java
```

Comment: Why don't you just extract all the files and delete the ones you don't need?

Comment: Where does this JAR come from? It's not a good practice to package the source and the class files in the same JAR...

Comment: Because it's uglier and slower solution. There's about 10000 files there.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `unzip` command which accepts wildcards in its arguments (which is not the case of the `jar` command). Something like this should do the trick ( disclaimer : not tested)

```
unzip youFile.jar "*.java"
```

Answer (score 53):

From the [source:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)

> To extract only certain files from a jar file, supply their filenames:
>
> `C:\Java> jar xf myFile.jar foo bar`

Using wildcards is a shell thing, and you should not expect it to work when *extracting* from a JAR file (which, as you've realized, is the case).

What you *can* do, is supply a list of the files you want to extract, via the `@` modifier:

```
jar xf my.jar @myfiles.lst
```

where `myfiles.lst` would be:

```
com/my/MyClass.java
com/my/MySecondClass.java
```

This file could easily be created automatically with creative use of `jar tvf`, `awk` and your desired extraction pattern. I'll leave that as an exercise and/or another SO question :-)

Or you could use `unzip` - a JAR file is basically a zip-file.

Cheers,

Comment: Ok I know it, this is in documentation, but does jar support any regexes? I've not found it anywhere:/

Answer (score -6):

There shouldn't be any *.java files in a jar, only class files. You can check the content of the jar first by running:

```
jar tvf jar-file.jar
```

Comment: It's not uncommon practice to publish source jars.

Comment: Excuse me but how is this an answer ?